# Having a hard time visualizing the call order of binary tree recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree, binary-tree, callstack

I am trying to visualize recursion for this particular problem solution below, and have placed 2 console.logs, but I still can’t understand it.
The problem:

[Node depths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYKZ7.png)

Here is my solution. It works though I don't fully understand why.

```js
function helper(root, depth) {
  console.log(depth, ‘step 1’)
  if(root === null) {
    console.log(depth, ‘step 2’)
    return 0;
  }

  if(root.left === null && root.right === null) {
    console.log(depth, ‘step 3’)
    return depth
  }

  console.log(depth, ‘step 4’)
  const leftSum = helper(root.left, depth + 1);
  const rightSum = helper(root.right, depth + 1);
   const totalSum = depth + leftSum + rightSum;
   return totalSum;
  
}

function nodeDepths(root) {
  return helper(root, 0);
}
```

In particular, for this input:

```js
{
  "tree": {
    "nodes": [
      {"id": "1", "left": "2", "right": null, "value": 1},
      {"id": "2", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 2}
    ],
    "root": "1"
  }
}
```

For the case where depth is equal to 1 and node.value is 2, the algorithm order goes like below

```
0 step 1
0 step 4
1 step 1
1 step 3
1 step 1
1 step 2
```

My question is why at depth === 1, the code doesn’t go to `step 4` after `step 3` but goes back up to `step 1` instead? And when a number is returned from the call stack, why is that number added to the sum of a branch (but not minus, multiply or divide)?

Thank you in advance! I’ve been stumped on this for the past 3 days.

I tried console.log out the callstack and expected it to go to step 4 after step 3 for when depth is equal to 1.

Comment: That data structure is not what you pass to your function. It wouldn't work. Your code expects `root.left` to be a node object, but in the data we see it is a string (`"left": "2"`), so the output you say you got is not coming from this input data. Please fix your question (and also JavaScript does not use curly quotes for string literals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You recurse twice, in the code here:

```
const leftSum = helper(root.left, depth + 1);
const rightSum = helper(root.right, depth + 1);
```

The four lines that are prefixed with depth 1 combine the two calls, two lines from each.

The first call is on the left child of the root, which is a valid leaf node, so you see `step 3` printed, since that's the base case for leaf nodes. The second recursion, on the right child, is running on a null value, and bails out in step 2, another base case.

It might help you better understand the recursion if you printed the `root` value, along with the depth.

As for why the depths are being added up, that I can't help you with. I just seems to be the task assigned in this exercise. I don't think there's any utility to that sum, unlike, for example, the maximum depth (which can be used to balance a tree, which helps make some algorithms more efficient).

Comment: Thanks. So I still don't understand why after `step 3`, the code doesn't go to `step 4`? I expected it will hit step 3 and return up for the leaf side, then go to step 4, then go to the right side because I saw that it goes there when depth is 0.

Comment: In the first recursive call, step 3 gets hit and it `return`s back to the original call. There's nothing printed in between the two recursive calls, so you go directly into the second recursion, which starts at the top (with step 1) and then goes to step 2 where it quits. All of the base cases `return`, so you won't ever see `step 3` immediately followed by `step 4`.

Comment: Got it, so why at depth === 0, I see that step 4 is printed out here?

Comment: Step 4 is the recursive case, it gets printed out just before you go to the two recursive calls. Neither of the base cases (steps 2 and 3) got hit at depth 0, so it continued on to step 4 and you see the output.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the execution flow, I would suggest to change what you actually log. Logging "step" may not be enough to get a clear view. I would suggest to log something when a recursive call is about to be made, and when execution comes back from that recursive call. And also indicate which of the two recursive calls it is (left or right). Finally, use `depth` to **indent** the output -- indented output gives a better clue as to what is happening.

(NB: that data structure your mentioned is not ready to be passed to your function, as it doesn't have *node* instances as values for `left` or `right` -- so I added function that converts it)

```js
function helper(root, depth) {
  let indent = "    ".repeat(depth);
  console.log(`${indent}helper(root.id==${root?.id}):`);
  indent += "    ";
  if(root === null) {
    console.log(`${indent}Root is null. return 0`);
    return 0;
  }

  if(root.left === null && root.right === null) {
    console.log(`${indent}This node is a leaf; return ${depth} (depth).`);
    return depth
  }

  console.log(`${indent}Making recursive call to the left.`);
  const leftSum = helper(root.left, depth + 1);
  console.log(`${indent}Back from left recursive call. leftSum==${leftSum}.`);
  console.log(`${indent}Making recursive call to the right`);
  const rightSum = helper(root.right, depth + 1);
  console.log(`${indent}Back from right recursive call. rightSum==${rightSum}.`);
  const totalSum = depth + leftSum + rightSum;
  console.log(`${indent}All done for this node. totalSum=${totalSum}. Return it.`);
  return totalSum;
}

function nodeDepths(root) {
  return helper(root, 0);
}

// Added this function to convert data structure to nested nodes
function createTree({tree: { nodes, root }}) {
    const map = new Map(nodes.map(obj => [obj.id, { ...obj }]));
    
    for (const obj of map.values()) {
        obj.left = map.get(obj.left) ?? null;
        obj.right = map.get(obj.right) ?? null;
    }
    return map.get(root);
}

const data = {
  "tree": {
    "nodes": [
      {"id": "1", "left": "2", "right": null, "value": 1},
      {"id": "2", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 2}
    ],
    "root": "1"
  }
};

const root = createTree(data);
nodeDepths(root);
```

I hope with this kind of logging the process becomes clearer.